# Laravel Eloquent One-To-One target works as property but not function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I setup the `user` - `phone` relationship explained in the laravel docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

```
    $user=Auth::user();
    $phone = $user->phone;

    var_dump($phone->toArray());
```

This worked fine, and displayed the phone data from the database.

What I don't understand is why I am using `$user->phone` instead of `$user->phone()`.

From the docs, my user model contains this **function**:

```
public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
}
```

But when I try to access `$user->phone()->toArray()`, it throws an error that the method is not found.

Why am I accessing `phone` as a property and not a function? Is it possible to use the function instead? My IDE does not recognize a `phone` attribute for $user, only the `phone()` function.

Comment: Try ```$user->phone()->get()->toArray()```

Comment: how about `$phone = $user->phone()->get();` then `$array = (array) $phone; dd($array);`

Comment: `$user->phone()` will return you an Eloquent relation, from which you can chain query builder functions. `$user->phone` returns you the the relation instance, which is an Eloquent model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your phone function is used for relationship, you have to call it as property. you may have missed the following line in the documentation.

> Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record
>   using Eloquent's dynamic properties. Dynamic properties allow you to
>   access relationship methods as if they were properties defined on the
>   model

When you call it as property, laravel understand this is a relationship with other table and execute it accordingly. since all relationships also serve as query builders, when you are calling **$user->phone()->toArray()**, returns query builder object and search toArray() function on that class.

Comment: Accepted this answer because you tried to explain what was happening. I ended up adding another method to `User` called `getPhone()` that returns `$this->hasOne('App\Phone')->first();` - this returns an instance of the model.

Answer (score 2):

Using brackets will return a query builder instance. This is usually more helpful for direct manipulation, for instance, if a user has many phones (I know in your case it's only one phone)

```
$activePhone = $user->phones()->where('status', 'active')->first(); 
//returns the first phone number with an active status
```

`toArray()` is not a member of query builder, thus, it won't work with

```
$user->phone()->toArray();
```